# Mysql Query to replace content

Tags: mysql

I found injected code in my MySQL database and it looks like the below code:

1)

```
<!--5449cd194ff8e1414122777-->
    <div style="display:none;">
         <a href="http://drivemir.ru/vybor-avto">выбор автомобилей по цене этого</a>
    </div>
<!--/5449cd194ff8e1414122777-->
```

2)

```
<!--5449cd194ff8e1414122777-->
    <div style="display:none;">
         Семинар «Продвижение бизнеса на англоязычные рынки»  <a href="http://topodin.com/seo/post/prodvizhenie-brenda">digital agency читай</a> Компания RIM2000 является одним из ведущих системных интеграторов Украины
    </div>
<!--/5449cd194ff8e1414122777-->
```

This code is different for each MySQL row but I've found that there is a common number in each script "5449cd194ff8e1414122777". so any one has solutions that how can I remove this script by finding this "5449cd194ff8e1414122777".

One more thing is this script is appended in every row at last of the content.

NOTE : I want to remove this script without affecting my other content in same column and row,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show your table definition ???

Comment: Instead of just removing the injected content you might want to a) prevent it from entering the database, b) prevent it from being useful if it did get inserted in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Finally i got solution:

UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_content` = replace(`post_content`,SUBSTRING(  post_content, INSTR( `post_content` , '' ) ,1000 ) ,'');